# Replacing word in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a word in a string with another word but code does not work.

NOTE: Preserve the case of the original word when you are replacing it.    For example, if you mean to replace the word "Book" with the word "dog", it should be replaced as "Dog"

What is wrong in code ?

```
function replace(str, before, after) {  

    // Find index where before is on string
    var index = str.indexOf(before);
    var dogru = before[0] === before[0].toUpperCase();
    var yanlıs = after[0] === after[0].toUpperCase();

    // Check to see if the first letter is uppercase or not
    if (dogru !== yanlıs) {
        if(dogru)
            after = after.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);
        else
            after = after.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + after.slice(1);
    }

    // Now replace the original str with the edited one.
    var str1 = str.split(' ');

    str1.splice(str1.indexOf(before),1, after);

    return str1.join(' ');
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

Comment: `"A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".replace('jumped', 'leaped')`

Comment: What's all the uppercase/lowercase stuff for? Is there an additional requirement related to case of the words?

Comment: You named you function `replace` and not `myReplace`. You also need a variable to store the result. [Other than that it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dwb9zetL/).

Comment: can you explain which error do you have? is in the console or is not working properly?

Answer (score 2):

You're over-complicating things my friend. Just use replace() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I don't recommend using w3schools as a link reference, MDN is better and more commonly used.

Comment: :). yes because of this I ask this simple question. I cant find where i make mistake by myself. I know solution and other methods. I wonder what is wrong and how can i fix this .

Comment: @yuga You just used the wrong function name (and didn't store the result), the algorithm itself is correct for the output you want. This answer does not really answer the question should be a comment.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I was thinking more of the lines that OP wants to just simply replace some string. If it's just a code review, shouldn't it be over at: codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didnt know that codereview.stackexchange.com. thanks i ask like that trivial questions in there.

Comment: @A.Lau [codereview.se] requires that the code already works as intended. OP explicitly states "code does not work" - it's a badly worded SO question, not a CR question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Works great all but the fact your calling the function `myReplace` when your defined function name is `replace`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace() method like below:

"A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".replace("jumped", "leaped");

Explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)